# Flowable project build issue in eclips

Tags: java, eclipse, flowable

Flowable project build issue in  eclipse

The project build was successful, but multiple modules showing the famous eclipse **"red x"** error.

[image]
have already tried to remove the error by using the clean and build approach

The Progress tab in eclipse showing the following error

[image]

Error details

[image]

is there any particular sequence to build this project?

Comment: Well what does it show when you open the Problems View and look at the details like it tells you to?

Comment: @greg-449 The errors below were detected when validating the file "BPMN20.xsd" via the file "CancelCallActivityTest.testActivityMessageBoundaryEventsOnCallActivity.bpmn20.xml".  In most cases these errors can be detected by validating "BPMN20.xsd" directly.  However it is possible that errors will only occur when BPMN20.xsd is validated in the context of CancelCallActivityTest.testActivityMessageBoundaryEventsOnCallActivity.bpmn20.xml.

Comment: In Eclipse, a project build issue is shown by a red exclamation mark at the project folder. In your case, the red `x` means the project contains errors that do not prevent building.